# loop use in switch case autoit

Tags: loops, switch-statement, autoit

I have a thousands mini tools, I am trying to create a menu by using Autuit. I have to define thousand functions and case and variable how i can make it easy.
here is my code how can use loop for select case and run soft.exe

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

$Form1 = GUICreate("MainMenu", 615, 437, 192, 124)

$Soft1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Button1", -8, 0, 75, 25)
$Soft2 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Button2", -18, 10, 75, 25)
$Soft3 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Button3", -28, 20, 75, 25)
$Soft4 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Button4", -38, 30, 75, 25)
$Soft5 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Button5", -48, 40, 75, 25)
$Soft6 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Button6", -58, 50, 75, 25)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)


While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
        Case $Soft1
        Startsoft1()

        Case $Soft2
        Startsoft2()

        Case $Soft3
        Startsoft3()

        Case $Soft4
        Startsoft4()

        Case $Soft5
        Startsoft5()

        Case $Soft6
        Startsoft6()
    EndSwitch
WEnd

Func  Startsoft1()
    Run('Soft1.exe')
EndFunc

Func  Startsoft2()
    Run('Soft2.exe')
EndFunc

Func  Startsoft3()
    Run('Soft3.exe')
EndFunc

Func  Startsoft4()
    Run('Soft4.exe')
EndFunc

Func  Startsoft5()
    Run('Soft5.exe')
EndFunc
```

iam new in programing there for learning new things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this as a good starting point.
Put the names and pathes in the strings of the method StringSplit.
The GUI buttons are automatically placed in a new line if the button reaches the GUI width end.

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

main()

Func main()
    Local $gui_width = @DesktopWidth -100, $gui_height = @DesktopHeight - 80
    Local $Form1 = GUICreate("MainMenu", $gui_width, $gui_height, 50, 10)

    Local $exesName_A = StringSplit('a.exe,b.exe,c.exe,d.exe,e.exe,f.exe,g.exe,h.exe,i.exe,j.exe,k.exe,l.exe,m.exe,n.exe,o.exe,a.exe,b.exe,c.exe,d.exe,e.exe,f.exe,g.exe,h.exe,i.exe,j.exe,k.exe,l.exe,m.exe,n.exe,o.exe', ',', 2)
    Local $exesPath_A = StringSplit('a.exe,b.exe,c.exe,d.exe,e.exe,f.exe,g.exe,h.exe,i.exe,j.exe,k.exe,l.exe,m.exe,n.exe,o.exe,a.exe,b.exe,c.exe,d.exe,e.exe,f.exe,g.exe,h.exe,i.exe,j.exe,k.exe,l.exe,m.exe,n.exe,o.exe', ',', 2)
    Local $height = 45, $width = 125, $y = 0, $x = 0
    Local $button_A[UBound($exesName_A)]

    For $i = 0 To UBound($exesName_A) - 1
        If ((8 + ($x + 1) * $width) > $gui_width) Then
            $y += 1
            $x = 0
        EndIf

        $button_A[$i] = GUICtrlCreateButton($exesName_A[$i], 8 + $x * $width, 10 + $y * $height, 75, $height)
        GUICtrlSetImage(-1, "shell32.dll", 22+ $i)
        $x += 1
    Next

    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

    While 1
        $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
        Switch $nMsg
            Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                Exit

        EndSwitch
        ; scan all buttons to check if one was pressed
        For $i = 0 To UBound($button_A) - 1
            If $nMsg = $button_A[$i] Then
                ConsoleWrite('Now run the exe' & $exesPath_A[$i] & @CRLF)
;~          ShellExecute($exesPath_A[$i], '') ; uncomment this to run the exe
            EndIf
        Next
    WEnd

EndFunc   ;==>main
```

Comment: please check its preview, now its show only 4 buttons in a line with gap. and its possible to show name and icon top and bottom as in windows we see

Comment: I thought you want to write the  code :-) Give it a try, and if need help on a concrete case then ask again for help.

Comment: no no I want just solution. but I tried when buttons increase 437 height its show  an error. please add some code for this problem. for example when buttons reach menu height its add sub menu or scroll down option. thanks a lot. you solved my problem in one page while I tried many time many method but I failed.

Comment: Instead of using a scroll function try the code above. Should be enough space for all your buttons :-)